# Pentaho JRC repository on Filesystem: how can I access it?

Tags: pentaho, jackrabbit

I am trying to access the various reports presents on "public" directory in Pentaho 5.0.1 . I know that those directories are under a JRC repository saved on the real filesystem. How can I view these files outside Pentaho?

Thank you

PS: we are using the Comunity Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no filesystem counterpart for the JCR files. You may want to look into the Pentaho Repository Synchronizer, a community plugin available in the Pentaho Marketplace, that will "sync" the JCR with a folder inside pentaho-solutions/system/repositorySynchronizer.

However, the sync is rather limited. It only checks for differences in filesize and does not track changes that have no size impact. Plus, when you sync, there's no control over which version gets written over. I advise you to be extremely careful with the synchronisation process, and only select the two copy modes: copy from JCR to filesystem and copy to JCR from filesystem.